# Excel VBA - Multiple Subs Doing the Same Thing for Different Items

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first question so be gentle, and I'm brand new to using VBA in Excel. I found a subroutine that accomplishes what I want: changing the color of a shape based on the input or value of a specific cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value < 10 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        ElseIf Target.Value >= 10 And Target.Value < 20 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        ElseIf Target.Value >= 20 And Target.Value < 30 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlue
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        End If
    End If
```

What I'd like to do, is to run that same exact sub for up to 5 shapes where the values appear in cells A1:A5. I'm sure this is easy but I just can't seem to find the solution in the documentation I have found. Is there a way to do this, or so all of them have to be in their own module?

Comment: What are the names of the shapes and to which cell should they be linked?

Comment: Can you try changing the first condition like this: `If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

Comment: You could get pretty sophisticated here, using collections and such to keep your code minimal, but if you're new to VBA I'd suggest just copying your code and amending it to suit the other shapes: If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then shape 1 ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Shape 2 etc

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much the following code of yours:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Exits, if the changed cell is not A1. You have to elaborate a bit, allowing not to exit, if the value is in A1:A5. This can be achieved with the following:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

`Cells(1,1)` is `A1` and `Cell(5,1)` is `A5`. They both declare the start and the end of the allowed range.

Here is the documentation of the `Worksheet_Change` event in MDSN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use `Select...Case` rather than `If...Then`.

Not sure how you identify which of the five shapes to update so I've used the Target row number - update row 1 and it updates Oval 1, row 2 updates Oval 2, etc.

Using the `Intersect` as suggested by @Vityata, except by placing the `Not` keyword in front of the Intersect it reverses the TRUE/FALSE answer - I try and have one exit point for each procedure so all code flows to the end and through any tidy-up lines that need executing.  I've highlighted this with the `Else` statement that just holds a comment (and can be deleted if you want).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))) Is Nothing Then
        'Value is the default property of Target so we can just say 'Target'.
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            'Select Case works a bit like If...Else If....Else...End If.
            'You can string expressions together: Case 10 To 19, 39 To 49, >100, <>102
            Select Case Target
                Case Is < 10
                    'Use the Target row to define the name of the shape.
                    'Pass that and the colour to the UpdateShape procedure.
                    UpdateShape Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row), vbRed
                Case 10 To 19
                    UpdateShape Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row), vbYellow
                Case 20 To 29
                    UpdateShape Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row), vbBlue
                Case Else
                    UpdateShape Shapes("Oval " & Target.Row), vbGreen
            End Select
        End If
    Else
        'Do nothing - Target is not within A1:A5.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateShape(ShapeRef As Shape, RGBColor As Long)
    ShapeRef.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGBColor
End Sub
```